# How to allow clickable link in GrowingTextView

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uitextview, clickable

I am working on a Native SMS application.

I am using Chat bubble in my view and to add text in that (I am using `UITextView`)

I want to allow Hyperlink on that Chat bubble ..

Like if someone msg me `www.google.com` then while i press on that chat bubble it should be open in Browser ...

I have use `GrowingTextView` like

```
txtViewGrowing.minNumberOfLines = 1;
txtViewGrowing.maxNumberOfLines = 4;
txtViewGrowing.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; 
txtViewGrowing.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];
txtViewGrowing.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtViewGrowing.delegate = self;
txtViewGrowing.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
      | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin 
      | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin 
      | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

txtViewGrowing.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
[txtViewGrowing setPlaceHolderText:@"Type to Compose"];

[self.view addSubview:txtViewGrowing];
//[txtViewGrowing.internalTextView becomeFirstResponder];


[txtViewGrowing sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:btnSend];
[txtViewGrowing resignFirstResponder];
```

Is there any property of `GrowingTextView` to allow Hyper link in that .. Else give me solution how can i make my chat bubble linkable ...

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score -1):

For **android**: you can use `autolink:web` in properties (if your working in eclipse) if not, add this to the XML of your textview: `android:autoLink="web"`.

This will convert each weblink in your textview to a clickable link.